# Remove symbols from text with field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, regular-expression

I'm attempting to remove € symbols from values in the attributes of a geopackage. For example, I have a value 240 123€ that I want to turn into 240 123.

I'm using the field calculator to do this. So far here's what I have written down.
`regexp_replace("myfield",'(^.*[0-9]+)','\\1')`

This gives the same results as
`regexp_replace("myfield",'([0-9]+)','\\1')`

Both of these result in 240 123€.

Comment: note that if you want to turn the value in a "real" number you will need to remove the space (thousand separator) as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

`replace("field_name", '€', '')`

Answer (score 6):

Why so complicated? Simply use: `regexp_replace("myfield",'€','')` - or even easier: `replace("myfield",'€','')`

Answer (score 4):

```
left("text",length("text")-1)
```

would work, too.

Comment: ...if the symbol to be removed is at the same place all time

Comment: I can only work with what OP provides to us @Babel ;-)